# Съезжают блоки сайта вниз, как с этим справиться?

Tags: css3, html5

Проблема в том что съезжает весь последний блок, если указать ширину у таблицы или у блока menu 100%, то съезжает вниз ровно на блок content-header -а.

И вторая проблема, когда ставлю блок с рамкой border в конец всего тела, она почему то появляется сверху блока, и не важно где ты ее расположишь.

Буду, очень признателен, если разжуете мне эту проблему более подробно.

```css
body {
 font-family:Arial,'Times New Roman', sens-serif;
 margin:0;
 padding: 25px 40px 25px 45px;
}

.clear {
 clear: both;
}

#logo table {
 width:100%;
}

.grey {
 color:#afaeae;
}

.green {
 color:#91aa77;
 font-weight:bold;
}

.right p {
 margin:0;
 font-style:italic;
 text-align:right;
}
#topmenu {
 background-color: #538bc5;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
#topmenu ul li {
 float:left;
 list-style: none;
}
#topmenu ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 display:block;
 font-size: 135%;
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

#topmenu ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

#topmenu ul .active a , #topmenu ul li a:hover {
 background-color: #375c84;
}


#contact {
 float:  right;
 margin: 10px 6px 0 0;
 text-decoration:none;
}

#header img {
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

#content-header {
 float: right;
 position:relative;
 top: -175px;
 right: 30px;
 text-align: right;
}

#content-header h1, #content-header h3 {
 margin: 0 0 0 0 ;
 }

#content-header h1 {
 color: #5F91B0;
 font-size: 215%;
}

#content-header h3 {
 color: #8AAEC0;
}

#content-header a{
 background-color: #F08221;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 font-size: 105%;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#content-header p {
 margin-top: 45px;
}


#search div input{
 float: right;
 border: 4px solid #cbddbb;
 width: 180px;
 padding-left: 5px;
 height: 25px;
 color: #676767;
}

#menu {
 margin-top: 5px;
}

#menu table{
 width: 69%;
 float: left;
}

#menu .right {
 margin:12px 2px auto auto ;
}

#menu .right {
 float: right;
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: -340px;
}

.border {
 border-top: 1px dashed blue;
 width: 100%;
}

#menu table table {
 width: auto;
}

#menu table td a {
 padding:10px 20px;
 display: block;
 text-decoration: none;
 background-color: #E7E7E8;
 color: #BCB9B8;
 margin:12px 2px auto auto;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#menu table td a:active, #menu table td a:hover {
 color: #356790;
 background-color: #DCEBF4;
}

#menu .active a {
 color: #356790;
 background-color: #DCEBF4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
<head>
<title>Верстка сайта</title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
<link rel='StyleSheet' type='text/css' href='styles/styles.css' />
</head>
<body>
 <div id='logo'>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><img src='images/logo.jpg' alt='logo'/></td>
    <td class='right'>
     <p class='grey'>For additional information. Contact Us!</P>
     <p class='green'>info@memostra.com</p>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
 <div id='topmenu'>
  <ul>
   <li class='active'>
   <a href='#'>
    <span>Home</span>
   </a>
   </li>
   <li>
   <a href='#'>
    <span>About</span>
   </a>
   </li>
   <li>
   <a href='#'>
    <span>Chothig</span>
   </a>
   </li>
   <li>
   <a href='#'>
    <span>Shoes</span>
   </a>
   </li>
   <li>
   <a href='#'>
    <span>Electronics</span>
   </a>
   </li>
   <li>
   <a href='#'>
    <span>Perfumes</span>
   </a>
   </li>
   <li>
   <a href='#'>
    <span>Contact Us</span>
   </a>
   </li>
  </ul>
  <div id='contact'>
   <a href='#'><img src='images/mail.jpg' alt='icon-mail'></a>
   <a href='#'><img src='images/facebook.jpg' alt='icon-facebook'></a>
  </div>
  <div class='clear'></div>
 </div>
 
 <div id='header'>
  <img src='images/head.jpg' alt='header'/>
  <div id='content-header'>
   <h1>Welcome to Mostra!</h1>
   <h3>Quality products - Great prices!</h3>
   <p>
    <a href='#'> Check it Out! </a>
   </p>
  </div>
 </div>
 
 <div id='menu'>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td class='left'>
    <table>
     <tr>
      <td class='active'> <a href='a'><span>All categories </span></a></td>
      <td> <a href='a'><span>Men </span></a></td>
      <td> <a href='a'><span>Women </span></a></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </td>
   <td class='right'>
    <div id='search'>
    <form name='search' action='#' method='post'>
     <table>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <div>
         <input type='text' name='searched' value='Browse Products'/>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type='image' src='images/button.jpg' alt='button'/>
       </td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    </form>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr> 
 </table>
 </div>
 <div class='border'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добрый день! Не понятно, в каком порядке должны в итоге идти блоки и что где должно быть расположено, можете описать подробнее? 1. порядок блоков 2. взаимное расположение блоков на странице. 3 не хотите ли прибегнуть к grid-css ? (не обязательно, но верстать будет проще=) ) 
Объясню на том, в чем вам удобнее писать, но поясните целевой макет

Comment: Блоки, идут в том порядке, как указаны в теле, т.е. 1.logo 2.contact 3.topmenu 4.header .5.menu и после 5-ого блока идет рамка. Идут они с верху вниз ровно по горизонтали. grid css даже о таком не слышал...

Comment: Как таковой проблемы нет, я это все дело подвинул через margin, но хотелось бы узнать почему съезжают при указании 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блоки съехали из-за правила position.
Если во множестве блоков стоит relative, они начинают позиционироваться относительно друг друга и конфликтовать.
Такое позиционирование лучше использовать только у четко зависимых друг от друга элементов (например - стрелочка у выпадающего списка должна быть привязана к первому пункту всегда и находиться внутри него)
В остальных случаях чтобы блоки не жили своей жизнью, лучше не использовать position.
Когда блок должен быть независим и остальные должны под него заезжать или на него, используйте background-color, чтобы не смешивался текст накладываемых элементов
grid css позволяет виртуально поделить страницу на заданную вами сетку и не дать элементам из разных блоков попасть в чужой сектор. Удобная технология, советую почитать.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы, поправил все это background -ом на блок хидер и все стало ок, За место тега img в самом теле. Но конечно же хотелось бы что бы и картинка и текст все было в одном, и без position не обойтись, так как текст "убегает" под картинку... Если же двигать простым margin.

Comment: Спасибо, догадывался, что что то не то с контент хидером... Но не понимал что, теперь понял .. position!!! :)

Comment: Ах да... Про рамку еще подскажите, почему она ставится сверху блока menu, хотя я явно прописваю блок после блока с menu <div class='border'></div>

Comment: Ещё можете обернуть картинку и Хидер в один див, задать ему ширину/высоту и уже его отпозиционировать как надо, а внутри расположить картинку с хидером относительно друг друга при помощи display:inline-block, margin и padding

Comment: Все что ниже в коде - выше на странице. Используйте css z-index. У нижнего блока задайте 0, а у верхнего 999. Вы же имеете ввиду наложение, да?

Comment: Для рамки не хотелось бы наложение и позиционирование использовать, так как рамка будет не одна, и все хочется сделать по грамматному) Задал параметры на ширину 100% и рамку  по топу и все, дальше только класс ставишь куда надо и рамка тебе )

Comment: Или я чего то непонимаю?)

Comment: Вы все правильно поняли, не понял я)
Это из-за float:left у #menu > table. вы заставляете обтекать таблицу слева, хотя она занимает 100% ширины и остальные блоки не всегда могут подстроиться под такие требования

Comment: Мысленно жму руку Константин, поправил все, спасибо!) а то сижу тупого ловлю, вкурить не могу...) Еще это можно обойти следующим образом указав в диве пустую таблицу <div class='border'><table><tr><td></td></tr></table></div> и все будет, ок :)

Comment: Некоторый костыль)